# error upgrade ios 6.1 and xcode to 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode

I upgraded my IOS to 6.1 and also my xcode.
Now i am getting strange error with RestKit or Json.

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_RKMIMETypeJSON",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help you . Go to **Build settings** in the Targets . There find the valid architecture . (Remove the armv7s only use the armv7)